# How to conclude if soldiers from one unit is connected on grid map

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine, graph-algorithm, game-physics

I am making game and map is like grid and I have couple units ( every unit has couple soldiers). How to conclude if soldiers from one unit is connected (connected means that every soldier has for neighbour at least at one direction soldier from same unit). Map is grid and neighbour cells are two which can differ at x and/or y just in 1 ( every cell except border has 8 neighbour cells, like matrix).

Comment: Not sure if your description is consistent. 1D example: `SS.SS` - 4 soldiers, all have one neighbour soldier, but the two sub-units are disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) in here, your graph is `G=(V,E)` where `V` is the grid and `E = { (u,v) | there is a soldier in both u and v from the same unit }`

Basically, when you reduce the problem to this graph, any graph discovery algorithm will do,. Invoke the algorithm from any of the soldiers in the desired unit, and you can tell if the unit is "connected" if the discovery algorithm discovered *exactly* `k` nodes, where `k` is the number of soldiers in the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union-find data structure.  Test each pair of soldiers.  Whenever two soldiers are adjacent, their equivalence classes are merged.  After testing for all such pairs, your unit is connected if you end up with a single equivalence class.